# Add public key to remote server's authorized keys and execute some commands

Tags: shell-script, ssh

This command on its own works:

```
ssh user@remote 'cat >>/home/user/somedir/.ssh/authorized_keys' <~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

So I tried to incorporate it into my script:

```
#! /bin/bash

ssh user@remote 'cat >>/home/user/somedir/.ssh/authorized_keys' <~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub << EOF
    touch hello
    mkdir /test/morning
    cp hello /test/morning
EOF
```

The aim is to copy my `id_rsa.pub` from my local machine to the `authorized_keys` file of the remote host and then execute some other commands but the commands using the script above are echoed into the `authorized_keys` file, like so:

```
$ cat /home/user/somedir/.ssh/authorized_keys 
    touch hello
    mkdir /test/morning
    cp hello /test/morning
EOF
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do complicated things in more than one step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are looking for,

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@remote "mkdir /home/user/somedir/.ssh; \
cat >> /home/user/somedir/.ssh/authorized_keys; touch hello; mkdir /test/morning; \
cp hello /test/morning"
```

I prefer to use `ssh-copy-id`. You just give it the remote address and it adds your public key to the `authorized_keys` file on the remote machine:

```
$ ssh-copy-id user@remote
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to execute a command before the `cat >> ...`? For example, run a script, create a directory to put `id_rsa.pub` in?

Comment: @Proletariat see my updated answer. Is that what you want ?

Comment: Pretty much but for some reason my `cat` seems to be empty if I do it after executing a script. The issue seems to be running a shell script with the one liner, doing, `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@remote "sudo myscript.sh; mkdir /home/user/somedir/.ssh; cat >> /home/user/somedir/.ssh/authorized_keys; touch hello; mkdir /test/morning; cp hello /test/morning"` not sure why this would break it. Without running `myscript.sh`, it works fine.

Comment: @Proletariat what your `myscript.sh` is doing ?  Can you please post content of it in your original question ?

Answer (score 2):

The [here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) redirects the standard input of the command you run (`ssh` in this case). So does the `< file` redirection. Redirections are processed from left to right, so the last redirection takes effect. So  `cat` runs on the remote and gets it input from the here document.

Try it with something like

```
echo file > sourcefile
cat <<EOF <sourcefile 
here doc
EOF
```

and then compare with the redirections in reverse order.